# How to make a piece of code wait till I enter some value in a text view?

Tags: java, android

[image: This image shows y^x button whose onClick event name is <code>yRaiseTox</code>]I want to make control execute the top two lines(before the single line comment) and wait till I enter some value in the text view.I am trying to achieve `y^x` by clicking a `Y^X` button whose `onClick` event name is `yRaiseTox`.

```
 public void yRaiseTox(View view){
    /**
     * on pressing this button following things are taking place
     * 1. Getting string from the text field
     * 2.Converting it into Integer to perform math operations
     * 3.Setting text field to null
     * 4.User will enter a value that will be x
     * 5.Using pow() to get the result and printing it back to the text field*/
    Integer y = Integer.parseInt(tv1.getText().toString());
    tv1.setText("");

    //  Now I want this code to be executed when I enter some value in the text view tv1
    Integer x = Integer.parseInt(tv1.getText().toString());
    tv1.setText(pow(y, x)+"");
}
```

Comment: Your user is supposed to enter some value on tv1? (which you can't do with textView)

Comment: @nlopez The value in text view will be y and after getting it I am setting tv1 to null so that I can enter a value for x.Now, I want that after getting the value of y control should wait for me till I enter a value for x and then finally compute y^x using pow().

Comment: You enter some value to tv1, the after click to the button you get y. With same way you get x and set result to tv1. Am I right ?

Comment: @BakhtiyorBegmatov That would require two buttons to separately fetch the values of x and y and then get the result.

Answer (score 1):

First of all users can't type in textviews, edittext is what you need. You could put the two different codes in if statements and have them execute under different conditions, but then the user will have to press the button twice. If you don't want your user to have to press twice, then you could also set an onTextChanged listener after you do

```
Integer y = Integer.parseInt(tv1.getText().toString());
tv1.setText("");
```

and then when text has been changed do that next part of code you want executed.

Comment: Users are not typing in textviews I've buttons in my app those would do the work of changing the string in textview.

Comment: ok i see, so you want that integer x part to happen when you set the text elsewhere in your code? why dont you just put it in a different method then and call that method after you set the text?

Comment: Could you elaborate it more by giving a snippet for instance?

Comment: sure, show me where you set the text after you do the first part

Comment: I've attached an image which will help you to better understand my problem.

Comment: After clicking on Y^X button string in the text view will be converted into Integer and that will be y and the text view will set to `null`.Now, I want the user to enter a value that would be `x` and `y^x` would be computed by pow().But, in order to achieve that the control has to wait till the user enters the value otherwise, an error would be generated as null will get converted into Integer. Hope this would be clear to you

Answer (score 1):

Creating calculator is seems easy at first glance but it isn't. I recommend you to use [State design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern). I have wrote some implementation.

1. **Create your state interface**

   ```
   public interface State {

       String getDisplayValue();

       State onButtonPressed(int buttonId);
   }
   ```

   Here I have created two methods. First returns string to display it. When user clicks to any button you pass button's id to second method and it returns the new state of calculator by given id. When new state you display its value to user any wait user's action
2. **Create interface for operations and implementation of pow operation**

   ```
   public interface Operation {

       enum Type {
           ADD,
           SUBTRACT,
           MULTIPLY,
           DIVIDE,
           SQRT,
           SQUARE,
           POW,
           NEGATE
       }

       BigDecimal getResult();
   }

   public class PowOperation implements Operation {

       private final BigDecimal base;
       private final BigDecimal power; 

       public PowOperation(BigDecimal base, BigDecimal power) {
           this.base = base;
           this.power = power;
       }

       @Override
       public BigDecimal getResult() {
           return BigDecimalMath.pow(base, power);
       }
   }
   ```
3. **Create implementations of states**

   ```
   public class AcState implements State {

       @Override
       public String getDisplayValue() {
           return "0";
       }

       @Override
       public State onButtonPressed(int buttonId) {
           switch (buttonId) {
               case R.id.button_0:
               case R.id.button_1:
               case R.id.button_2:
               case R.id.button_3:
               case R.id.button_4:
               case R.id.button_5:
               case R.id.button_6:
               case R.id.button_7:
               case R.id.button_8:
               case R.id.button_9:
                   return new ValueState(buttonId);

               // TODO return another states according which button is pressed

               default:
                   return new AcState();
           }
       }
   }

   public class ValueState implements State {

       private BigDecimal value;
       private NumberFormat valueFormatter = new DecimalFormat("# ###.###");

       public ValueState(int initalValue) {
           value = BigDecimal.valueOf(initalValue);
       }

       @Override
       public String getDisplayValue() {
           return valueFormatter.format(value);
       }

       @Override
       public State onButtonPressed(int buttonId) {
           // TODO not implemented
       }
   }

   public class OperationState implements State {

       private final BigDecimal value;
       private final Operation.Type operationType;
       private NumberFormat valueFormatter = new DecimalFormat("# ###.###");

       public OperationState(BigDecimal value, Operation.Type operationType) {
           this.value = value;
           this.operationType = operationType;
       }

       @Override
       public String getDisplayValue() {
           return valueFormatter.format(value);
       }

       @Override
       public State onButtonPressed(int buttonId) {
           switch (buttonId) {
               case R.id.button_0:
               case R.id.button_1:
               case R.id.button_2:
               case R.id.button_3:
               case R.id.button_4:
               case R.id.button_5:
               case R.id.button_6:
               case R.id.button_7:
               case R.id.button_8:
               case R.id.button_9:
                   return new SecondValueState(value, operationType, buttonId);
       }
   }

   public class SecondValueState extends ValueState {

       private final BigDecimal firstValue;
       private final Operation.Type operationType;

       public SecondValueState(BigDecimal firstValue, Operation.Type operationType, int initalValue) {
           super(initalValue);
           this.firstValue = firstValue;
           this.operationType = operationType;
       }

       @Override
       public State onButtonPressed(int buttonId) {
           switch (buttonId) {
               case R.id.button_equals:
                   return performOperation();

               // TODO implement here handling for other buttons
           }
       }

       protected State performOperation() {
           Operation operation = null;

           switch (operationType) {
               case Operation.Type.POW:
                   operation = new PowOperation(BigDecimal firstValue, BigDecimal secondValue);
                   break;

               // TODO implement here creation other operations according operation type
           }

           return new ResultState(operation != null ? operation.getResult() : BigDecimal.ZERO);
       }
   }

   public class ResultState extends State {

       private final BigDecimal resultValue;
       private NumberFormat valueFormatter = new DecimalFormat("# ###.###");

       public ResultState(BigDecimal resultValue) {
           this.resultValue = resultValue;
       }

       @Override
       public String getDisplayValue() {
           return valueFormatter.format(value);
       }

       @Override
       public State onButtonPressed(int buttonId) {
           // TODO not implemented
       }
   }
   ```

In above code you set `AcState` as initial state. When user clicks to any button `AcState` returns `ValueState` (user is entering some number). In `ValueState` if user clicks to any operation buttons (like addition, subtraction and etc.) you return `OperationState` where firstValue is fixed and user had chosen operation. When user again starts entering numbers `OperationState` returns `SecondValueState`.

Finally when user press equals button `SecondValueState` performs calculation and returns `ResultState`

Advantage of this pattern is all logic is separated in small classes and easy to extend. Disadvantage is you have to write A LOTS OF CODE!

Answer (score 0):

Make a boolean gettingY and set it to true. The first time you click the y^x button, it will do the first part and the second time you press it, it will do the second part.

```
     public void yRaiseTox(View view){

        if(gettingY){
           Integer y = Integer.parseInt(tv1.getText().toString());
           tv1.setText("");
           gettingY = false;
        } else {
           Integer x = Integer.parseInt(tv1.getText().toString());
           tv1.setText(pow(intValue, valueOfx)+"");
           gettingX = true;
        }
    }
```